# Custom Draw TAction Dropdown menu

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, taction

I create a drop down menu for a TActionClientItem with list of TAction. I would like to know how can I hook the drawing event for the menu or each TAction inside to display the caption of those TAction in differente way !? 
Something like TAction.OnDrawItem or TActionClientItem .OnDrawItem ...

```
procedure xxxxx.BuildActionMenu;
var
  iLoop : Integer;
  oItem : TAction;
  oClientItem : TActionClientItem;
begin
  if Assigned(oClientItem) then
    for iLoop := oClientItem.Items.Count - 1 downto 0 do
      oClientItem.Items.Delete(iLoop);

  for iLoop := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    oItem := TAction.Create(actionList);
    oItem.Caption := List[iLoop].Name;
    oItem.Tag := iLoop;
    oItem.OnExecute := HandleOnExecuteMenuItem;
    **oItem.OnDraw = WhateverFunction**
    oClientItem .Items.Add.Action := oItem;
  end;

  if Assigned(oClientItem) then
  begin
    if oClientItem.CommandProperties is TButtonProperties then
      TButtonProperties(oClientItem.CommandProperties).ButtonType := btSplit;
    TAction(oClientItem.Action).OnExecute := HandleOnExecuteParentItem;
    **oClientItem.OnDraw = WhateverFunction**        
  end;
end;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Custom drawing event handlers are always attached to the UI components and not to actions. So with the plain VCL you cannot do what you ask.

It would be simple enough to derive your own action class that added an OnDraw event. You would also have to derive your own dropdown menu class to provide the other end of the connection.